# Tab switch issue in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, integration-testing, puppeteer

I have an error during tab switch in puppeteer:

```
await page2.waitForSelector('#save');   
await page2.click('#save');  //for saving and closing the page
await page2.waitFor(4000);  // !!it will crash if I remove this line!!
const allPages = await browser.pages();
const page1 = await allPages[0];  
await page1.waitFor(5000);// change nothing even if I wait 10 seconds
await page1.waitForSelector("selector")//crash if I delete 3rd line
```

When I run this code without the 3rd line, it triggers an error :

> error:  Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Session closed.
>   Most likely the page has been closed.
>       at CDPSession.send(c:\path\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:172:29)
>       at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (c:\path\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:56:77)
>       at EventEmitter._document._documentPromise._contextPromise.then (c:\path\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:310:38)

And `page2.waitForNavigation` does not work for me, it freezes the page.

I wonder why it crashes if I don't use the function : **waitFor(4000)** on page2 and if there is a way to automate the wait for not wasting time for nothing

Or maybe I should wait for page2 completely close after click a button?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for the `script` to finish executing :

```
await page.waitForResponse(response => {             
    return response.request().resourceType() === 'script';
});
```

Or wait for other things to load/happen/finish, differents `ressourceType` : `document, stylesheet, image, media, font, script, texttrack, xhr, fetch, eventsource, websocket, manifest, other`